# Neutral element in $S_n(X)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Then the nth singular chain module of $X$, denoted by $S_n(X)$, is defined as the free abelian group generated by all singular $n$-simplices, i.e. by all continuous maps $\Delta^n\rightarrow X$.

Can somebody say what the neutral element in this group is?
I got this question because I was told that if $X\neq\emptyset$, then we have a non-trivial element, the constant map $\Delta^n\rightarrow X, a\mapsto x$.

But why shouldn't this constant map be non-trivial?

Comment: Basis elements in a free module will never be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be a bit unclear on what exactly is a free $R$-module $F$ (in particular free abelian group) over a set $S$. The basic idea is that the elements of a set are *declared to be the basis* in the group $F$. The elements of the group $F$ are the *formal linear combinations* of the elements of $S$ with coefficients in $R$, i.e. expressions of the form
$$
\sum_{s\in S}r_s s,
$$
where $r_s\in R$ and $r_s$ are zero for all but finitely many $s$. The zero element in $F$ is then the unique element where all $r_s$ are zero. A key thing to note is that the elements of the set $S$ do not, on their own, influence the algebraic structure of $F$. For instance, a free abelian group on the set $\{a\}$ is isomorphic to a free abelian group on the set $\{b\}$ via the map $a\mapsto b$, which is extended by $R$-linearity. If you find this unclear, you might want to think about vector spaces, which are just free modules over their bases.

Hopefully, this provides some background to the answer by N.H. Namely, the neutral element does not correspond to any particular singular simplex, since singular $n$-simplices form the basis of $S_n(X)$ by definition. The neutral element is in fact a chain (a formal linear combination of simplices) of the form $0 = \sum_{\sigma : \Delta^n \to X} 0\cdot[\sigma]$.

P.S.: There can be some technical problems if the ring $R$ is arbitrary. For the above discussion you can safely assume that $R=\mathbb{Z}$ or any other PID, where everything is very similar to vector space theory.

Answer (score 0):

The neutral element is simply zero, i.e the chain $0 = \sum_{\sigma : \Delta^n \to X} 0.[\sigma$].

In particular, if $\sigma' : \Delta^n \to X$ is constant, the associated chain is $[\sigma']$, which is not trivial since it has a coefficient $1$.

Comment: Thank you, but what is the corresponding element in $S_n(X)$? Since $X$ must not have a zero, the map $a\mapsto 0$ makes no sense for me.

Comment: I don't understand sorry. The chain $0$ does not correspond to any map. An element in $S_n(X)$ won't correspond to a map but $\mathbb Z$-linear combinaisons of map. In particular, if $\sigma : \Delta^n \to X$ is _any_ map, then we can take the combinaison $[\sigma]$ which is not equal to the zero combinaison in $S_n(X)$.